# Way in HTML to prevent Chrome prompting to save address?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a simple form like Google AutoComplete, where there's an input, it suggests answers, which then fills in a multi-part form in the background and submits it.  The problem is, when I submit that form it asks if I want to save the address every time.

Is there a way to prevent Chrome from prompting for this?  I've already tried autocomplete="off" or autocomplete="new-password" or autocomplete="do-not-autofill" (from herer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/713874) without luck.

Here is the URL: https://bss.addons.la/trips/booking/triage/

And here is the thing I'm trying to prevent from happening using code:
[image]

Comment: My understanding is this is user-browser specific (and it's based on user preference) - specially so if they have a plugin/extension that they want to use for these casese

Comment: In the site I'm working on, the user manages customers and has the ability to update the customer's contact info, including their address. This is not the user's address, so I need a way to prevent it from asking the user to save the customer's address.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the solution that sits well with my OCD, but it's the only solution I've found so far.

In order to get Chrome to stop prompting my users to save the address information, I obscured my input "name" attributes.

**Before**

```html
<input name="address1">
<input name="address2">
<input name="city">
<input name="state">
<input name="zip">
```

**After**

```html
<input name="a1">
<input name="a2">
<input name="c">
<input name="s">
<input name="z">
```

This worked for me, but I'd prefer a more programmatic way of handling this, but until then.